# How to work with string.format for nth parameter dynamically generated jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to replace element placeholder with respected values, this works fine for  hardcoded as shown in **snippet 1** ,

i need to make it work for  dynamically loook **snippet 2,3** .i.e if both variable **uiStructure, arrItem** are dynamically generated then how to handle it.

**[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7q3znvqk/1/)**

**Snippet 1:**

```
var uiStructure = "<div class='cntHolder'><h1>{0}<h1><div class='descDiv'>{1}</div></div>";
var arrItem = [];
    arrItem[0] = "label";
    arrItem[1] = "desc";

for (var i = 0; i < vWork.length; i++) {
 // how to set this dynamically, depend on arrItem 
  var getData = String.format(uiStructure, vWork[i].label, vWork[i].desc); 
  console.log(getData);
}
```

---

```
if (!String.format) {
                String.format = function (format) {
                    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
                    return format.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function (match, number) {
                        return typeof args[number] != 'undefined' ? args[number] : match;
                    });
                };
            }
```

---

Dynamicaly generated with many possibility like below:

**Snippet 2:**

```
var uiStructure = "<div class='cntHolder'><div class='imgDiv'>
<img src='{0}' alt='pic' /></div><div class='descDiv'>{1}</div>
<span>{2}</span> </div>";
var arrItem = [];
    arrItem[0] = "badge";
    arrItem[1] = "desc";
    arrItem[2] = "tagline";
```

**Snippet 3:**

```
var uiStructure = "<div class='cntHolder'><div class='imgDiv'><img src='{0}' alt='pic' 
/></div><div class='descDiv'>{1}</div></div>";
var arrItem = [];
    arrItem[0] = "badge";
    rrItem[1] = "desc";



  var vWork = [
            {

                label: "CEO",
                desc: "Higher Command",
                tagline: "The boss ",
                priority: "High",
                badge: "../01;jpg"
            },
            {
                label: "Developer",
                desc: "Programming developer",
                tagline: "Developer rocks",
                priority: "Medium",
                badge: "../02;jpg"
            },
            {
                label: "HR",
                desc: "Human resource",
                tagline: "Developer hate HR",
                priority: "Medium",
                badge: "../03;jpg"
            },
            {
                label: "Chairman",
                desc: "Boss of Boss",
                tagline: "no tagline available lol",
                priority: "Very High",
                badge: "../04;jpg"
            }
        ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach for dynamic property names:

```
for (var i = 0; i < vWork.length; i++) {
    var props = arrItem.map(function(prop) {
        return vWork[i][prop];
    });
    var getData = String.format.apply(null, [uiStructure].concat(props));
    console.log(getData);
}
```

How it works. You have an array of keys `arrItem`. In every iteration you want to get corresponding values for `vWork[i]`. [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) allows you to transform (it actually returns new array) keys array to array of respecting values from `vWork`. So `props` will look something like this:

```
["Chairman", "Boss of Boss"]
```

Finally you use [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) because you want to call String.format function providing arguments as an array.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7q3znvqk/2/

Comment: Thank you so much, this works , pls can you explain in more details, or share any useful link, thanks again for answering

Comment: Sure, I will add explanation to the answer.